# Make a synchroneous request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, request

I am trying to make a post request using NodeJS and request. 
I tried using promises and the async/await like other post says but I can manage to make work.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require("request");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var token = '';
process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;

function postRequest(options) {
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);

        token = (JSON.parse(body)).access_token;
        console.log(token + 'tet');
        return (token);
    });
}

async function requestToken() {
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://simplivity@xxxx/api/oauth/token',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        formData:
        {
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: 'administrator@vsphere.local',
            password: 'xxxx'
        }
    };
    try {
        var test = await postRequest(options)
        return (test);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

var test = requestToken();
console.log(test + 'TOT');
```

This is the answer :

```
[object Promise]TOT
00bd0beb-8967-4534-8c63-2e5d0d6876d4tet
```

Which should be the opposite.

thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you mean "Make an asynchronous request..."?

Comment: nop, I want to wait for the request to end before doing console.log. I should get tet then TOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(async () => {
  var test = await requestToken();
  console.log(test + 'TOT');
})();
```

While not very tidy something like this should work.

Better:

```
requestToken()
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: This. And also `postRequest` needs to be a promise

Comment: Thank you this works like a charm. And if I add other functions after the requestToken, will it still wait for the request to end?

Comment: No, only if you keep the functions inside the async function of the first example, or if you add an additional `then` to the second example. I suggest you look in to the async/await pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a promise.

Change your `postRequest` to:

```
function postRequest(options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);

            token = (JSON.parse(body)).access_token;
            console.log(token + 'tet');
            resolve(token);
        });
    });  
}
```